# Authentication MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication

Anyone can help me?

I am trying to authentication a user in my database but i am geting error "auth fails".

I've already started the database mongod with --auth option and created a user in my database.
But when i try to run command -> `"mongo 192.168.2.2/db_name -u user -p 123"` it says `"auth fails"`

The pass and the user is the same.
The user has all admin and cluster roles.
If i try to log without admin roles it says "Not authorized for query on admin.system.users"

running the command `db.auth("user","123")` returns true to me.
i've already tried to add the user with `db.addUser("user","123")` and `db.addUser({name: "user", pwd: "123", roles: ["dbAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin"]})`

Any tips?

Comment: did you try `use admin`? see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

Comment: Yes always i type this command to use the admin database, i've already did all steps in the mongo Docs like 89 times.

Comment: Anyone can help with this?

Comment: It looks like you do everything right. Try to give more info.. Can you upload printscreen of your shell commands?

Comment: @Yaron i'm thinking that i NEED to create a user to mongoDB and give permissions to him to enable making queries, also to authenticate. I am using the #root of linux.
Because everytime i try to authenticate i got this error: not authorized for query on admin.system.users code 16550

Comment: Which database did you create your user account in? Was it the same as the `db_name` you are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

If you no have `setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0` in your config, join in mongo shell without loggin, of course, loggin in `admin db` and add user in all databases.

you can use this

First **join in admin database**.

**First Method**

```
db.addUser({user: "test",pwd:"123", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin"], otherDBRoles:{otherdb1: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]}})
```

**Second Method**

```
db.addUser("test","123")
db.auth("test","123")
```

and repeat this in all databases.

**Differences:**

First method **only have all privilegies when you loggin directly in admin db**, but if you loggin in other db with admin user, wont work because you have this user in admin db, no in others db.

Second method if you loggin in any databases you have all roles in all db.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, i just tried to connect/make with this exmaples u gave me. Nothing works.
See my last comment on my post.
Thank you!